# Верный ли цикл While

Tags: java, while

Написал функцию которая ожидает синхронизацию файлов путём ожидания когда их md5 хеши будут одинаковые

```
public void waitUntilSynced() {
    String md5CMHostsFileSuorce = Commands.md5(file1);
    String md5CMHostsFileDest = Commands.md5(file2);
    int count = 0;

    while (md5CMHostsFileSuorce != md5CMHostsFileDest)) {
            reporter.fail("Sync failed", eFailureType.Timeout);
        }
        Sleep.sleep(20);
        count++;
    }
    reporter.log(String.format("Sync is done after \"%s\" seconds", count*20));
}
```

Вопрос следующий - будет ли при каждом цикле while меняться(обновляться) значение `md5CMHostsFileSuorce` и `md5CMHostsFileDest`?

Comment: Нет, значения переменных обновлятья не будут. Переинициализируйте их вручную внутри блока `while`

Comment: даже если убрав лишние скобки Вы сможете скомпилировать этот код, while будет уходить в вечный цикл, т.к. Вы сравниваете  не содержимое строк (хэшей), а адреса их объектов. Такое сработает только если обе строки null или md5() выдает закэшированный объект на одинаковые хэши, что маловероятно.